# Error when use WMI to get username in C++

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, wmi

I'm getting an error when I try to use WMI to get the computer's username:

> Error: Security must be initialized before any interfaces are marshalled or unmarshalled. It cannot be changed once initialized.

When I reverse the order between `CoInitialize()` and `CoInitializeSecurity()`, I get this error:

> Error: CoInitialize has not been called.

Code is below:

```
HRESULT hres;
std::string userNametest;

// Initialize COM
hres = CoInitialize(NULL);
    if (FAILED(hres)) {
        _com_error err(hres);
        LPCTSTR errMsg = err.ErrorMessage();
        std::wstring w = errMsg;
        userNametest = std::string(w.begin(), w.end());
        CoUninitialize();
        if (jadedevlog.is_open()) {
            jadedevlog << "Error: " << userNametest << endl;
            jadedevlog.close();
        }
        return 1;
    }
        // Initialize security
    hres = CoInitializeSecurity(
        NULL,
        -1,
        NULL,
        NULL,
        RPC_C_AUTHN_LEVEL_DEFAULT,
        RPC_C_IMP_LEVEL_IMPERSONATE,
        NULL,
        EOAC_NONE,
        NULL);
        if (FAILED(hres)) {
            _com_error err(hres);
            LPCTSTR errMsg = err.ErrorMessage();
            std::wstring w = errMsg;
            userNametest = std::string(w.begin(), w.end());
           
            if (jadedevlog.is_open()) {
                jadedevlog << "Error: " << userNametest << endl;
                jadedevlog.close();
            }
            CoUninitialize();
            return 1;
        }
            // Obtain the initial locator to WMI
            IWbemLocator* pLoc = NULL;
            hres = CoCreateInstance(
                CLSID_WbemLocator,
                0,
                CLSCTX_INPROC_SERVER,
                IID_IWbemLocator,
                (LPVOID*)&pLoc);

            if (FAILED(hres)) {
                CoUninitialize();
                userNametest = "fail to create WbemLocator"; // Failed to create WbemLocator
                if (jadedevlog.is_open()) {
                    jadedevlog << "Error: " << userNametest << endl;
                    jadedevlog.close();
                }
                return 1;
            }
                // Connect to WMI through the IWbemLocator::ConnectServer method
                IWbemServices* pSvc = NULL;
                hres = pLoc->ConnectServer(
                    L"ROOT\\CIMv2",  // WMI namespace
                    NULL,
                    NULL,
                    0,
                    NULL,
                    0,
                    0,
                    &pSvc);

                if (FAILED(hres)) {
                    pLoc->Release();
                    CoUninitialize();
                  
                    userNametest = "Cant connect to WMI"; // Could not connect to WMI
                    if (jadedevlog.is_open()) {
                        jadedevlog << "Error: " << userNametest << endl;
                        jadedevlog.close();
                    }
                    return 1;
                }
                    // Set security levels on the proxy
                    hres = CoSetProxyBlanket(
                        pSvc,                        // Indicates the proxy to set
                        RPC_C_AUTHN_WINNT,           // RPC_C_AUTHN_xxx
                        RPC_C_AUTHZ_NONE,            // RPC_C_AUTHZ_xxx
                        NULL,                        // Server principal name
                        RPC_C_AUTHN_LEVEL_CALL,      // RPC_C_AUTHN_LEVEL_xxx
                        RPC_C_IMP_LEVEL_IMPERSONATE, // RPC_C_IMP_LEVEL_xxx
                        NULL,                        // client identity
                        EOAC_NONE                    // proxy capabilities
                    );

                    if (FAILED(hres)) {
                        pSvc->Release();
                        pLoc->Release();
                        CoUninitialize();
                  
                        userNametest = "Could not set proxy blanket"; // Could not set proxy blanket
                        if (jadedevlog.is_open()) {
                            jadedevlog << "Error: " << userNametest << endl;
                            jadedevlog.close();
                        }
                        return 1;
                    }
                        // Use the IWbemServices pointer to make requests of WMI
                        IEnumWbemClassObject* pEnumerator = NULL;
                        hres = pSvc->ExecQuery(
                            L"WQL",
                            L"SELECT * FROM Win32_ComputerSystem",
                            WBEM_FLAG_FORWARD_ONLY | WBEM_FLAG_RETURN_IMMEDIATELY,
                            NULL,
                            &pEnumerator);

                        if (FAILED(hres)) {
                            pSvc->Release();
                            pLoc->Release();
                            CoUninitialize();
                          
                            userNametest = "fail to query for Win32_ComputerSystem"; // Query for Win32_ComputerSystem failed
                            if (jadedevlog.is_open()) {
                                jadedevlog << "Error: " << userNametest << endl;
                                jadedevlog.close();
                            }
                            return 1;
                        }
                            // Retrieve the data from the query in step 6
                            IWbemClassObject* pclsObj = NULL;
                            ULONG uReturn = 0;

                            while (pEnumerator) {
                                HRESULT hr = pEnumerator->Next(WBEM_INFINITE, 1, &pclsObj, &uReturn);

                                if (0 == uReturn) {
                                    userNametest = "no more time";
                                    break; // No more items
                                }

                                VARIANT vtProp;
                                // Get the value of the "UserName" property
                                hr = pclsObj->Get(L"UserName", 0, &vtProp, 0, 0);

                                int wslen = SysStringLen(vtProp.bstrVal);
                                int len = WideCharToMultiByte(CP_UTF8, 0, vtProp.bstrVal, wslen, nullptr, 0, nullptr, nullptr);
                                if (len <= 0)
                                    userNametest = "Convertion fail";  //convert from BSTR to string fails
                                std::string result(len, 0);
                                WideCharToMultiByte(CP_UTF8, 0, vtProp.bstrVal, wslen, &result[0], len, nullptr, nullptr);

                                VariantClear(&vtProp);
                                pclsObj->Release();
                                userNametest = result;
                            }

                            // Cleanup
                            pSvc->Release();
                            pLoc->Release();
                            pEnumerator->Release();
                            CoUninitialize();
```

What happened?

Comment: On a side note: DO NOT call `CoUninitialize()` if `CoInitialize()` fails. And `std::string(w.begin(), w.end())` is not the correct way to convert a `std::wstring` to `std::string`, you need to use `std::wstring_convert` or equivalent instead. Also, you are not doing any error checking on the `HRESULT` that `pEnumerator->Next()` or `pclsObj->Get()` return.

Comment: Just wondering why one would use WMI instead of a simple call `GetUsername(Ex)` ? WMI is really meant for scripting languages and is to be avoided like the plague for desktop apps given it's performance overhead.

Comment: @Remko because I need to get username from Remote connection in a server, GetUsername returns Local System user in this case

Answer (score 1):

`CoInitializeSecurity()` can only be called one time per process. It will return `RPC_E_TOO_LATE` if it has already been called.  Although this is an error condition (ie, `FAILED()` will return true for it), it is not a *fatal* condition, but you are treating it as if it were.  If you invoke this code multiple times in a single process, you will need to ignore `RPC_E_TOO_LATE` when checking `CoInitializeSecurity()` for failure.

Similarly for `RPC_E_CHANGED_MODE` on `CoInitialize()`.  It is an error condition, but not a *fatal* condition. It just means that `CoInitialize/Ex()` was already called by the calling thread using a different concurrency model than the current call is requesting. In that case, COM is already initialized on the calling thread, so you can move forward, just don't call `CoIninitialize()` when you are done since *your* call to `CoInitialize()` technically "failed".

Try this:

```
HRESULT hres;
...

// Initialize COM
hres = CoInitialize(NULL);
bool doCoUninit = SUCCEEDED(hres);
if (FAILED(hres) && (hres != RPC_E_CHANGED_MODE)) {
    ...
    return 1;
}

// Initialize security
hres = CoInitializeSecurity(...);
if (FAILED(hres) && (hres != RPC_E_TOO_LATE)) {
    ...
    if (doCoUninit)
        CoUninitialize();
    return 1;
}

...

if (doCoUninit)
    CoUninitialize(); 
...
```

Comment: Thanks, it works now but went in this condition now:if (0 == uReturn) {
                                    userNametest = "no more time";
                                    break; // No more items
                                }